# What happens when a collection in Java increases beyond capacity?

Tags: java, jvm

I have a service which stages all calls made to it in memory, because we don't want to lose the data and at the same time we need this service to ever fail due to any external dependency (like a DB for example). These staged calls are then routinely picked up and processed in the background.

If, for any reason, if there are too many calls and we run out of memory, we need to be alarmed.

So, the question simply put, is this: What exception do I need to catch or monitor on to notify me when an addition to a list fails due to insufficient resources? Will it result in an OOM in the VM itself, or is there a collection-level limit as well?

If there is no collection-level limit, how would you recommend I monitor the usage of the service? Currently, we have heap usage and memory usage metrics. Are those enough? Also, the JVMs are configured to kill on an OOM error (this is because the VM manager then restarts any process it is managing on a kill).

Comment: In terms of memory, you will get an OOME. If you want to limit the elements going into a collection, you'd have to implement that yourself.

Comment: We should avoid this kind of situation at first place I would say, instead use some file based cache.

Comment: That seems easy enough to test. Write a simple application that adds items to a collection in an infinite loop and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception to be thrown is `OutOfMemoryException`. This exception can be thrown in any part of your application, once your collection eats all available heap space.

However if you know that it can be potentially thrown for a specific collection, the best way might be to prevent this to happen, i.e. cap this collection or use caching, so that unused entities are evicted and reloaded on demand. For a lightweight cache implementation I would recommend Guava's [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html).

**UPDATE**

Since everybody suggests FS-based storage, here is my lightweight drop-in proposal:

- [CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) to load your serialized data from NoSQL DB
- [Kryo](https://code.google.com/p/kryo/) serializer to convert your objects into `byte[]`
- [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/) to store (or any other embedded NoSQL solution you prefer).

Comment: All answers till now have been great, but alas.. I can select only one. Since this post summarizes it all I'm marking this as the right one. Thank you for taking time!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I found in the specification of Collection.add :

> If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason other than that it already contains the element, it must throw an exception (rather than returning false). This preserves the invariant that a collection always contains the specified element after this call returns.

It doesn't specify which exception, so different collections may throw different exceptions.

Comment: Since it is important for us to be making sure data gets added or otherwise we are notified, this is surely something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I think letting the application fail miserably is not an ideal design choice. You should have threshold on the size of the collection and decide what to do in that case: flush it somewhere (disk?), send a notification (JMX/email), throw an error (or let the OOME propagate).

That said, I'm going to give you a design recommendation. From your brief and slightly cryptic description of the service, it sounds to me like you need a work queue to sit somewhere *outside* of your service, e.g., a JMS server or even a database. In this way, your background process will be able to pickup the request from the queue (db) and process it even if your service died for any reason.

Comment: Completely makes sense and is definitely the right way to go. In place of the DB though, I am going with FS based storage (slowing down on external dependency is a bigger concern for us than to be losing the data - we are fine with a few occurrences of data loss). Thanks for taking the time